# Binding element visibility to a ViewModel property, with design-time support

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, fody-propertychanged

I've got a WPF application using Caliburn.Micro. I want to be able to overlay the application with a shadow and progress ring (from [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/)) when I want the application to wait for some work to be done in the background.

What I have at the moment actually works but the overlay is always-on at design time. My `ShellView` window looks like this:

```
<Window ...>
    ...
    <Grid>
        ...
        <Rectangle x:Name="waitShadow" Fill="#3f000000" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Visibility="{Binding IsWaiting, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        <ContentControl ... Visibility="{Binding IsWaiting, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <Controls:ProgressRing ...> <!-- from MahApps.Metro -->
            </Controls:ProgressRing>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My `ShellViewModel` class has a public bool property `IsWaiting` and when I set it to `true` the shadow and ring comes up and everything is disabled. When I set it to `false` it goes back to normal, so the binding works (I'm using [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) with the PropertyChanged addin). The only problem is that the `Visibility` property isn't collapsed at design time.

Is there a better way to have an overlay that works at design time?

Comment: does ShellViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Fody with PropertyChanged

Comment: So you just want to set a value at design time?

Comment: Yes, the current `Visibility` binding doesn't default back to `Collapsed` like I thought it would

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a `FallbackValue` on your binding, that will `Collapse` it in design time

```
Visibility="{Binding IsWaiting, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"
```

You could also make `IsWaiting` a `DependancyProperty` and set the default there, But I find this the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

FallbackValue doesn't always work, i.e. if your designer is actually bound to design time data, and FallbackValue actually modifies run-time behaviour of the binding which may be less than desirable in many situations. I made a markup extension that lets designers fiddle with the UI in the designer without worrying about messing up run-time behaviour. I wrote about it here: http://www.singulink.com/CodeIndex/post/wpf-visibility-binding-with-design-time-control

It can be used like this:

```
<Grid Visibility="{data:Value {Binding RootObject, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}, DesignValue=Visible}">
    <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="Testing visibility" />
</Grid>
```

The code for ValueExtension is as follows (any updates or bug fixes will be posted to the blog so I suggest checking there for the latest version):

```
public class ValueExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public object DesignValue { get; set; } = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

    [ConstructorArgument("value")]
    public object Value { get; set; } = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

    public ValueExtension() { }

    public ValueExtension(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var provideValueTarget = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
        var property = provideValueTarget.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
        var target = provideValueTarget.TargetObject as DependencyObject;

        if (target == null || property == null)
           return this;

        object value = DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(target) && DesignValue != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue ? DesignValue : Value;

        if (value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || value == null)
            return value;

        if (value is MarkupExtension)
            return ((MarkupExtension)value).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);

        if (property.PropertyType.IsInstanceOfType(value))
            return value;

        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property.PropertyType).ConvertFrom(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, it works perfectly for me with design-time bound data sources. Thanks.